# Why didn't someone make Lily and James Potter portraits like the dead Hogwarts Headmasters?

Tags: harry-potter

After

> Dumbledore dies in book 6

A portrait appears of him (same as all other former headmasters) in his old office and is able to talk, display emotions, and show intelligence.

If this is really

> Dumbledore

Why didn't someone find a way to make a portrait for Lily and James Potter, so that they(their portrait that seems to be exactly the) could communicate, not just for Harry's sake, but there would definitely be some propoganda and strategic value for them being able to communicate.

Comment: (a) it's not Dumbledore from beyond the grave; it's pretty much just a good copy as I understand it (b) Lily and James didn't know they were going to die until they did, how would that have been set up?

Comment: I don't think these are duplicates. The old question basically asks the difference between paintings and photos. The new question asks why no one made a painting of Lily and James.

Comment: @robopuppy - Which the top answer to the other question also addresses **"JKR**: *If Harry had a portrait of his parents it would not help him a great deal.*"

Comment: @Valorum - In the interview, JK Rowling said that it wouldn't help Harry, but there are reasons beyond Harry that someone would try, JK Rowling never said that it wasn't possible. By the way, this question is not just asking about Harry, and the answer you cited, doesn't fully answer my question.

Comment: While the edit makes the question more _clear_, the answer on the duplicate question still addresses what it takes to make those types of portraits (and, therefore, why no one could make one of the Potters), which is why I voted to leave as a duplicate.

Comment: @CreationEdge But it doesn't really address what it takes to make a portrait other than the vague assertion that it takes "complex magic." The Pottermore entry on portraits makes it clear, for example, that making a portrait that is "like the dead Hogwarts Headmasters" is very time consuming for the subjects. This is a probable reason why James and Lily who were busy being involved in a war and hiding from Voldemort didn't have one done. Nowhere is this addressed in the answer.

Comment: @robopuppy I cast my vote and gave my reasons for transparency and guidance for improving the question. If you think the question can be further improved, please [edit] it, or ask a new one along the specific lines of inquiry you've presented regarding essences, as this current question muddles it up with "propaganda and communication".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54336/discussion-on-question-by-hyperdrive-enthusiast-why-didnt-someone-make-lily-and).